# Вывод категорий в нужном порядке symfony 3

Tags: symfony3, twig

Нужно выводить категории по id сейчас категории выводятся по алфавиту.
Как реализовать вывод по id?

Код:

Вывод категорий

```html
{% for child in categories %}
  <div class="b-block-grid__item">
    <a class="b-category-link" href="{{ child.getAbsoluteUrl() }}">
      {% if child.image %}
      <img src="{{ child.image|imagine_filter('rise_category_thumb') }}"
                                         class="b-category-link__image"/>
      {% else %}
      <span class="b-category-link__image b-category-link__image_noimage"></span>
      {% endif %}
      <span class="b-category-link__name">{{ child }}</span>
    </a>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Контроллер

```html
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function searchAction(Request $request)
    {
        $searchForm = $this->createForm(SearchForm::class, [], [
            'method' => 'GET'
        ]);

        if ($searchForm->handleRequest($request) && $searchForm->isValid()) {
            $q = $searchForm->get('q')->getData();

            $qs = Product::objects()
                ->published()
                ->filter(new QOr([
                    ['name__icontains' => $q],
                    ['sku__icontains' => $q],
                    ['content__icontains' => $q],
                ]));

            $pager = $this->createPagination($qs, [
                'pageSize' => 12,
            ]);

            return $this->render('rise/product/search.html', [
                'products' => $pager->paginate(),
                'pager' => $pager->createView(),
                'search_form' => $searchForm->createView(),
            ]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('rise/product/search.html', [
                'search_form' => $searchForm->createView(),
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function autocompleteAction(Request $request)
    {
        $searchForm = $this->createForm(SearchForm::class, [], [
            'method' => 'GET'
        ]);

        $products = [];
        if ($searchForm->handleRequest($request) && $searchForm->isValid()) {
            $q = $searchForm->get('q')->getData();

            $products = Product::objects()->published()->master()
                ->filter(new QOr([
                    ['name__icontains' => $q],
                    ['sku__icontains' => $q],
                    ['content__icontains' => $q]
                ]))->limit(20)->all();
        }

        return $this->render('rise/product/_autocomplete.html', [
            'products' => $products
        ]);
    }

    protected function getCollections(Category $category = null)
    {
        $qs = Collection::objects();
        if ($category) {
            $qs->filter(['categories__id__in' => $category->id]);
        }
        return $qs->all();
    }

    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $categories = Category::objects()->order(['name'])->all();

        $filter = $request->query->get('filter', []);
        $filterForm = $this->createForm(FilterFormType::class, $filter, [
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('admin_rise_product_list')
        ]);

        return $this->render('rise/product/index.html', [
            'categories' => $categories,
            'filterForm' => $filterForm->createView(),
        ]);
    }

    public function listAction(Request $request, $slug = null)
    {
        $category = null;
        if ($slug !== null) {
            $category = Category::objects()->get(['slug' => $slug]);
            if (null === $category) {
                throw new NotFoundHttpException();
            }
        }

        $qs = Product::objects()->published();
        if ($category) {
            $qs->filter(['category__id' => $category->id]);
        }

        if ($request->query->has('order')) {
            $sourceOrder = $request->query->get('order');
            if (false === empty($sourceOrder) && in_array($sourceOrder, ['', 'price', '-price'])) {
                $qs->order([$sourceOrder]);
            }
        }

        $filter = $request->query->get('filter', []);
        $filterForm = $this->createForm(FilterFormType::class, $filter, [
            'category' => $category,
        ]);
        $filterForm->handleRequest($request);
        if ($filterForm->isSubmitted()) {
            $this->get('rise.bundle.product.filter.product')->filterQuerySet($filterForm->getData(), $qs);
        }

        $pager = $this->createPagination($qs, [
            'pageSize' => 12,
        ]);

        $collections = $this->getCollections();

        if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            return $this->render('rise/product/_list.html', [
                'products' => $pager->paginate(),
                'pager' => $pager->createView(),
                'category' => $category,
                'collections' => $collections,
                'filterForm' => $filterForm->createView(),
            ]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('rise/product/list.html', [
                'products' => $pager->paginate(),
                'pager' => $pager->createView(),
                'category' => $category,
                'collections' => $collections,
                'filterForm' => $filterForm->createView(),
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function viewAction(Request $request, $slug)
    {
        $product = Product::objects()->published()->get(['slug' => $slug]);
        if ($product === null) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException();
        }

        $history = $this->get('rise.bundle.product.component.product_history');
        $history->add($product);

        $related = $product->related->all();

        $review = new Review(['product' => $product]);
        $reviewForm = $this->createForm(ReviewForm::class, $review, [
            'method' => 'POST',
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('rise_product_view', ['slug' => $slug])
        ]);
        if ($reviewForm->handleRequest($request) && $reviewForm->isValid()) {
            $review = $reviewForm->getData();
            if (false === $review->save()) {
                throw new \RuntimeException('Failed to save review');
            }

            $this->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch(
                ReviewEvent::EVENT_NAME,
                new ReviewEvent($review)
            );

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Спасибо за ваш отзыв! Мы опубликуем его после проверки.');

            return $this->redirect($request->getRequestUri());
        }

        $reviewPager = $this->createPagination($product->reviews->filter(['is_published' => true]));

        return $this->render('rise/product/view.html', [
            'product' => $product,
            'images' => $product->getImages(),
            'related' => $related,
            'reviews' => $reviewPager->paginate(),
            'review_pager' => $reviewPager->createView(),
            'review_form' => $reviewForm->createView(),
            'collections' => $product->collection->all(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот тут, в данном методе:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $categories = Category::objects()->order(['name'])->all();

    $filter = $request->query->get('filter', []);
    $filterForm = $this->createForm(FilterFormType::class, $filter, [
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('admin_rise_product_list')
    ]);

    return $this->render('rise/product/index.html', [
        'categories' => $categories,
        'filterForm' => $filterForm->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Тут идет сортировка по имени. Сделайте просто по ID, а дальше, дам где требуется, так же.

Я говорю про строку `$categories = Category::objects()->order(['name'])->all();`